# List of all universities by country

Tags: data-request, geospatial, education

Is there a list of all universities by country including their websites, location, latitude and longitude, facebook, twitter, youtube, founding year etc. I can't believe such a data set is not publicly available.

Comment: also take a look at http://www.utexas.edu/world/univ/alpha/ as a checklist to make sure Wikipedia didn't miss any US ones. Also see https://data.ny.gov/Education/Post-Secondary-Universe-Survey-2010-Directory-info/uc4u-xdrd? which has information you are looking for but only for U.S. Institutions

Comment: ~15 years ago, I was working on a system for tracking of licensed engineers ... I used the ABET acredidation list.   You might be able to use other acredidation lists, and then de-duplicate them.  (some are by field, some are by geographical region, so many are acredited by more than one group)

Comment: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/4892/25665 Hi, also interested in this topic. Just a question, as a no coder, how could I use this query in Google Sheet ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

Wikipedia's sister project **[Wikidata](https://www.wikidata.org/)** provides data about [more than 18,000 universities](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20?item%20?itemLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase:label%20%7B%20bd:serviceParam%20wikibase:language%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%22.%20%7D%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20SELECT%20DISTINCT%20?item%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20?item%20p:P31%20?statement0.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20?statement0%20(ps:P31/(wdt:P279*))%20wd:Q3918.%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D) with a varying amount of detail.

You can use the [Wikidata Query Builder](https://query.wikidata.org/querybuilder/?uselang=en&query=%7B%22conditions%22%3A%5B%7B%22propertyId%22%3A%22P31%22%2C%22propertyDataType%22%3A%22wikibase-item%22%2C%22propertyValueRelation%22%3A%22matching%22%2C%22referenceRelation%22%3A%22regardless%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22Q3918%22%2C%22subclasses%22%3Atrue%2C%22conditionRelation%22%3Anull%2C%22negate%22%3Afalse%7D%5D%2C%22limit%22%3A100%2C%22useLimit%22%3Afalse%2C%22omitLabels%22%3Afalse%7D) to generate the following SPARQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
  {
    SELECT DISTINCT ?item WHERE {
      ?item p:P31 ?statement0.
      ?statement0 (ps:P31/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q3918.
    }
  }
}
```

This returns a list of all [instances (P31)](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P31) of [university (Q3918)](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q3918) and any of its [subclasses (P279)](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P279) (such as [institute of technology](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q1371037) or [law school](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q1321960)).

By slightly tweaking the above query, you can even generate an [interactive tree view of all countries and universities](https://query.wikidata.org/embed.html#%23defaultView%3ATree%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fcountry%20%3FcountryLabel%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%22.%20%7D%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fitem%20%3Fcountry%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20p%3AP31%20%3Fstatement0%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP17%20%3Fcountry.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fstatement0%20%28ps%3AP31%2F%28wdt%3AP279%2a%29%29%20wd%3AQ3918.%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0AORDER%20BY%20%28%3FcountryLabel%29%20%28%3FitemLabel%29) backed by live data from Wikidata.

Answer (score 8):

You can use Wikipedia to create your own dataset. It will not be hard. Here are a few details:

[List of all universities by country](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_universities_and_colleges_by_country)

Divided by continent and country, you have a list of all the universities

Then in every wikipedia page of a university, you can find as many details you want:

For example, in [Aristotle University of Thessaloniki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aristotle_University_of_Thessaloniki) you can find coordinates, founding year, website etc.

Comment: This is a smart community.  I can create a dataset from Wikipedia but it wont be easy even with http://www.kimonolabs.com/. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @user3237694 - correct that it's not easy but it seems like this will be your best bet. My suggestion is to collect a list of universities by traversing the Wikipedia index pages and then go about parsing all the Wikipedia entries. Some will have structured data in the right sidebar, some will not. For those without, there are probably a few patterns like "founded in XXXX" and "established in YYYY" to get some of the data out of the free-text.

Comment: @user3237694 : consider searching dbpedia for `rdf:type <http://schema.org/CollegeOrUniversity>`; see http://stackoverflow.com/q/17056476/143791