# Where can I find university/college addresses for the entire world?

Tags: data-request, education, global, address

I need to make an address locator to associate my data set to universities. In order to do this I need reference data that has the university addresses everywhere in the world. Can someone direct me toward a database with all the universities and colleges found across the world?

Comment: https://OSM.org has the data and you can use https://overpass-turbo.eu/ to build queries

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of all universities by country](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3426/list-of-all-universities-by-country)

Answer (score 1):

You can find the dataset here -:

https://www.datazar.com/project/p3d688124-3fc2-4130-9532-429780fb4d81

P.S- I worl for datazar, an open source datalibrary, where people can share, discover and work with data.

Comment: Site is not working.