# Comprehensive database of world universities

Tags: data-request, education, global

There are quite a lot of university rankings available on the web. Unfortunately, in most of them the data display is limited and is hard to extract systematically.

What are good sources for comprehensive datasets on world universities? For example, datasets that include the performance in several knowledge areas, teaching, research, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3426/list-of-all-universities-by-country?rq=1. ( you should  do the ranking yourself anyway)